# Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, difference in result between raw data and precomputed percentage data

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov

I'm trying to implement the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test from the Scipy package to test if there is a difference in the distribution of two samples. The samples are T-shirts sizes (S, M, L, XL and XXL) sold in two different periods. I want to test whether the distribution of sizes differs between the two periods.

The problem I have is that I get very different results when I pre-calculate the percentages of total for each size compared to using the raw data. I don't understand this as the percentages still represent the same distribution.

Here is the code I've used (x and y is raw data, x1 and y1 is the calculated percentages):

```
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp

x = (254, 526, 576, 622, 409)
y = (92, 214, 366, 365, 287)

x1 = (10.6, 21.9, 24.0, 25.9, 17.1)
y1 = (7.0, 16.2, 27.7, 27.7, 21.7)


print(ks_2samp(x, y))
print(ks_2samp(x1, y1))
```

And these are the two different results that I get:

Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.80000000000000004, pvalue=0.03614619076928504)
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.40000000000000002, pvalue=0.69740487802059081)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test is invariant under a scaling of the data, if the *same* scaling is applied to both samples.  By converting the samples to percentages, you have applied a different scaling to the two samples.  Specifically, you multiplied the first data set by 100/2387, while multiplying the second data set by 100/1324.

---

By the way, I don't think the Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test is appropriate for this data.  The KS test is for samples from a continuous distribution.  I would expect to model your data as the observed frequencies in a sample from a discrete distribution whose sample space is {S, M, L, XL, XXL}.  One common tool for the analysis of such data is the chi-squared test for a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table), which is implemented in scipy as [`scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html):

```
In [110]: x
Out[110]: array([254, 526, 576, 622, 409])

In [111]: y
Out[111]: array([ 92, 214, 366, 365, 287])

In [112]: a = np.vstack((x, y))

In [113]: a
Out[113]: 
array([[254, 526, 576, 622, 409],
       [ 92, 214, 366, 365, 287]])

In [114]: from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

In [115]: chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(a)

In [116]: p
Out[116]: 2.1980217327784848e-08
```

Be careful how you interpret this, because ["with enough data, everything is significant"](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/statistics-and-quality-data-analysis/large-samples-too-much-of-a-good-thing).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that clarified it for me.